# refactor large switch-statement

Tags: refactoring, switch-statement, conditional-statements

Any suggestions for refactoring this ugly case-switch into something more elegant?

This method (in Ruby) returns a (short or full) description for Belgian provinces, given a zipcode.

```
def province(zipcode, short = false)
  case zipcode
  when 1000...1300
    short ? 'BXL' : 'Brussel'
  when 1300...1500
    short ? 'WBR' : 'Waals-Brabant'
  when 1500...2000, 3000...3500
    short ? 'VBR' : 'Vlaams-Brabant'
  when 2000...3000
    short ? 'ANT' : 'Antwerpen'
  when 3500...4000
    short ? 'LIM' : 'Limburg'
  when 4000...5000
    short ? 'LIE' : 'Luik'
  when 5000...6000
    short ? 'NAM' : 'Namen'
  when 6000...6600, 7000...8000
    short ? 'HAI' : 'Henegouwen'
  when 6600...7000
    short ? 'LUX' : 'Luxemburg'
  when 8000...9000
    short ? 'WVL' : 'West-Vlaanderen'
  when 9000..9999
    short ? 'OVL' : 'Oost-Vlaanderen'
  else
    fail ArgumentError, 'Not a valid zipcode'
  end
end
```

Based on suggestions from MiiinimalLogic i made a second version. It this preferable?

```
class Provincie
  ProvincieNaam = Struct.new(:kort, :lang)

  PROVINCIES = {
    1000...1300 => ProvincieNaam.new('BXL', 'Brussel'),
    1300...1500 => ProvincieNaam.new('WBR', 'Waals-Brabant'),
    1500...2000 => ProvincieNaam.new('VBR', 'Vlaams-Brabant'),
    2000...3000 => ProvincieNaam.new('ANT', 'Antwerpen'),
    3000...3500 => ProvincieNaam.new('VBR', 'Vlaams-Brabant'),
    3500...4000 => ProvincieNaam.new('LIM', 'Limburg'),
    4000...5000 => ProvincieNaam.new('LIE', 'Luik'),
    5000...6000 => ProvincieNaam.new('NAM', 'Namen'),
    6000...6600 => ProvincieNaam.new('HAI', 'Henegouwen'),
    6600...7000 => ProvincieNaam.new('LUX', 'Luxemburg'),
    7000...8000 => ProvincieNaam.new('HAI', 'Henegouwen'),
    8000...9000 => ProvincieNaam.new('WVL', 'West-Vlaanderen'),
    9000..9999  => ProvincieNaam.new('OVL', 'Oost-Vlaanderen')
  }.freeze

  def self.lang(postcode)
    provincie_naam(postcode).lang
  end

  def self.kort(postcode)
    provincie_naam(postcode).kort
  end

  def self.provincie_naam(postcode)
    PROVINCIES.each { |list, prov| return prov if list.cover?(postcode) }
    fail ArgumentError, 'Geen geldige postcode'
  end

  private_class_method :provincie_naam
end
```

Comment: which language is it?

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear. It's in ruby.

Comment: This question actually belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (I'm a moderator there).  *If this code works as intended*, you may repost it there and delete the question here.

Comment: What is your goal of refactoring? Just making code look neater? It seems pretty easy to follow already. Or do you want to reduce complexity? I'm sure you can use binary search here on intervals, even though there are some overlapping ones.

Comment: it works as intended, but I'm not convinced this is the best way to do this. Does anyone have a suggestion for doing this in fewer LOC or just simpler.

Comment: there are no overlaps. Notice that the ranges with 2 dots include the endpoint, ranges with 3 dots do not include endpoints

Comment: @Jamal perhaps you should also explain why it belongs on CodeReview and why it doesn't belong on SO. Thanks.

Comment: Right.  The OP is looking for refactoring the code into something better, rather than looking to fix errors.

Answer (score 0):

Personally,  I'd specify the zip ranges & Province information in a different data structure a la Map of Range objects/Provinces, then use Ruby's Range methods to check if the result falls in the range with the range's method.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider having just one range lookup, either as is done here or with a map structure, with a secondary lookup (probably in a map) from the short description to the long description.